# Custom Installer for Unix Platform to install Python, Java, MySQL

Tags: bash, docker, installation, software-distribution, installation-package

We need to distribute a tool which is developed using Python, Java and MySQL as database in a distributable format.

So if end user is installing our tool, we check for Python, and if it not exists then we would install Python from the disk and not from apt-get. The process repeats for Java and MySQL which are run as sub-process, so that everything happens in sequence.

We could have used Docker images, but it runs in a container and we would not like our application to run within a restricted environment. Is this understanding correct that we would not have complete access to 100% of the resources in case of Docker?

What should be our approach and if anybody can share their experience in creating such distributable would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @amit-pandey, you would have more luck with that question on quora

Comment: You could unconditionally use `apt-get install python` If already installed, it will skip that installation.